# CF8 - Sum in a loop

Tags: mysql, loops, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, addition

I have a query:

```
<cfquery name="getDesc" datasource="#ds#">
  SELECT
    desc,
    SUM(charge) as cost,
    COUNT(*) as cnt
  FROM
    product
  WHERE Length(desc) > 0
</cfquery>
```

Which then populates a table:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Amount of Charges</th>
        <th>Cost (&pound;)</th>
      </tr>

      <cfoutput query="getDesc">
      <tr>
        <td>
          #HTMLEditFormat(getDesc.desc)# <br />
        </td>     
        <td>
          #HTMLEditFormat(getDesc.cnt)# <br />
        </td>
        <td>
            #HTMLEditFormat(getDesc.cost)# <br />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </cfoutput>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My problem is that I'd like to combine two rows of the table that have the same value and also have both of their counts added together.

So far I have:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Amount of Charges</th>
        <th>Cost (&pound;)</th>
      </tr>

      <cfoutput query="getDesc">
      <tr>
        <cfif getDesc.desc EQ 'No Charge' OR getDesc.desc EQ 'No Charge (2)'>
          <td>
            No Charge & (2)
          </td>
          <td>
            <cfset cntSum = arraySum(getDesc['cnt'])>
            #cntSum#
          </td>
        <cfelse>
        <td>
          #HTMLEditFormat(getDesc.desc)# <br />
        </td>     
        <td>
          #HTMLEditFormat(getDesc.cnt)# <br />
        </td>
        </cfif>
        <td>
            #HTMLEditFormat(getDesc.cost)# <br />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </cfoutput>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But this gives me two rows of 'No Charge & (2)' and the count is the sum of all the rest of the rows in the table rather than just the two rows I want.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would change your query around to get you the data you need. Here's what I've just whipped up which I think would meet your requirement:

```
  SELECT
    CASE `desc` WHEN 'No Charge (2)' THEN 'No Charge' ELSE `desc` END,
    SUM(charge) as cost,
    COUNT(*) as cnt
  FROM
    product
  WHERE Length(`desc`) > 0
  group by CASE `desc` WHEN 'No Charge (2)' THEN 'No Charge' ELSE `desc` END
```

The case statement is changing 'No Charge (2)' into 'No Charge' so there's only one row for both kinds of values. The group by statement is making mySQL perform the sum and count once per different value of 'desc'.

Comment: Nice Barney.  Your profile is a bit sparse.  I'd like to see your website.  Come to think of it, I just moved mine and my personal site is non-existent.  Hmmm... I guess I know what I'm going to be doing the rest of today!